'Invert' perturbed vorticity equation to forced Euler system
Given the vorticity form of the Euler equations in $2D$ with stream function $\psi$
\begin{align}
\omega_t + \nabla^\perp \psi \cdot \nabla\omega &= 0 \\
\Delta \psi = \omega
\end{align}
we know that $v =: \nabla^\perp \psi$ with $\text{curl } v = \omega$ solves the classical Euler equations
\begin{align}
 v_t + (v \cdot \nabla) v &= -\nabla p \\
 \text{div } v &= 0 \\
 v(0, \cdot) = v_0
\end{align}
for some pressure term $p$.

Question:
If instead we're given a perturbation of the vorticity-stream formulation such that $\Delta \psi = \omega + \varepsilon \phi$ --
Is there a clean way of showing that one can 'invert' the perturbed vorticity formulation to  an Euler system with forcing term of the 'same size' as the perturbation?

Could you perhaps briefly comment on the notation? $\nabla^\perp$ is the vector curl, and $\operatorname{curl}$ the scalar curl? If the stream function $\psi$ and $\omega$ are scalar and, what is then $\omega_t +\nabla^\perp\psi\cdot \omega$?

Thank you @BertoldoBaccalà -- there is a a typo in there, $\nabla^{\perp}$ is just the counter-clockwise rotated gradient by $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I missed the gradient on $\omega$.
